# traefik expose internal metrics

Tags: traefik

I would like to expose internal metrics of traefik.
After reading the documentation I created the following configuration file:

```
logLevel = "INFO"
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.dashboard]
    address = ":16081"
# API definition
[api]
  entryPoint = "dashboard"
  dashboard = true
  debug = false
  [api.statistics]
    recentErrors = 10
# Metrics definition
[metrics]
  # DataDog metrics exporter type
  [metrics.datadog]
    address = "172.17.0.1:8125"
    pushInterval = "10s"
################################################################
# Mesos/Marathon Provider
################################################################
# Enable Marathon Provider.
[marathon]
endpoint = "http://mesos.lan:8080/"
watch = true
domain = "service.lan"
exposedByDefault = false
```

When I query the dashboard entrypoint I got a 404 error on /metrics:

```
curl -s http://localhost:16081/health | jq
{
  "pid": 1,
  "uptime": "3h31m3.5252748s",
  "uptime_sec": 12663.5252748,
  "time": "2018-09-04 16:53:17.7128687 +0000 UTC m=+12663.602939001",
  "unixtime": 1536079997,
  "status_code_count": {},
  "total_status_code_count": {
    "404": 5
  },
  "count": 0,
  "total_count": 5,
  "total_response_time": "390.7µs",
  "total_response_time_sec": 0.0003907,
  "average_response_time": "78.14µs",
  "average_response_time_sec": 7.814e-05,
  "recent_errors": [
    {
      "status_code": 404,
      "status": "Not Found",
      "method": "GET",
      "host": "localhost:16081",
      "path": "/metrics",
      "time": "2018-09-04T16:53:12.0232879Z"
    },
    {
      "status_code": 404,
      "status": "Not Found",
      "method": "GET",
      "host": "localhost:16081",
      "path": "/metrics",
      "time": "2018-09-04T13:18:52.7206202Z"
    },
    {
      "status_code": 404,
      "status": "Not Found",
      "method": "GET",
      "host": "localhost:16081",
      "path": "/metrics",
      "time": "2018-09-04T13:18:51.853093Z"
    },
    {
      "status_code": 404,
      "status": "Not Found",
      "method": "GET",
      "host": "localhost:16081",
      "path": "/metrics",
      "time": "2018-09-04T13:18:50.9894516Z"
    },
    {
      "status_code": 404,
      "status": "Not Found",
      "method": "GET",
      "host": "localhost:16081",
      "path": "/metrics",
      "time": "2018-09-04T13:18:49.8598176Z"
    }
  ]
}
curl -s http://localhost:16081/metrics
404 page not found
```

Did I miss something ?

My main objective is to be able to get metrics per frontend/backend.
I would like to be able to know the number of requests and returned status code per frontend.

Thanks,

Renaud

Comment: Maybe it is your configuration of `127.17.0.1:8125` try `localhost:8125` instead, as stated in the documentation: https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/metrics/

Comment: Hi, Traefik sent metrics to datadog, that part works fine. I did not configure 127.0.0.1 but 172.17.0.1. I have available in datadog: traefik.config.reload.total, traefik.backend.server.up. My question is why endpoint /metrics does not work with my configuration. thank you for your help.

Comment: Sry, that was a typo. I meant `172.17.0.1`. The point is you are telling traefik to server the `/metrics` Endpoint at `172.17.0.1:8125` But you try to request it from `http://localhost:16081/metrics`. In order to resolve it you have to either request the metrics endpoint from the address specified or change the address to `address = "localhost:16081".

Comment: This is unrelated, it's the datadog configuration. I configured Traefik to send metrics to a Datadog endpoint to collect metrics.  This is different that having Traefik exposing internal metrics.

Comment: This is solved, solution is here: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3877

Comment: Cool, thanks for asking and sharing. Can you also write it as an answer to your question and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

This is solved, long story short, /metrics is only exposed when promotheus provider is enable. When Datadog provider is enable all the metrics are sent to datadog.

Details can be found here: github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3877